# Which Rails skeleton app is up to date with Rails 2.3.4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Would appreciate any recommendations as a lot of skeleton apps I see are out of date.

Comment: This question was post number 1,500,000 on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Because the url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500000/ goes here, and that number is the post number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure about skeleton apps, but a short browse through GitHub for Rails templates might help you get around better.